Is on the fly use of FormFile class appropriate for uploading files?
I am using Azure function to populate 'Content controls' in word document and upload the same to SharePoint (using Graph SDK).  I am able to achieve this with the below code, i did not want to create temporary files in Function host and hence have used FormFile object to create a clone (doc.Clone(outputStream, true)).  I am not sure if FormFile was designed to be used in this manner, or, are there any downsides with this approach?  If not FormFile what other .net class can be used?
Note:  I have passed memoryStream object while uploading file and the end result is a corrupted file in the destination.
public static Stream Merge(Stream downloadStream, string xmlString, string fileName)
{
 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     downloadStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
     {
         var main = doc.MainDocumentPart;
         main.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(main.CustomXmlParts);
         var customXmlPart = main.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
         using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString)))
         {
             customXmlPart.FeedData(dataStream);
         }

         var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
         doc.Clone(outputStream, true);
         var x = new FormFile(outputStream, 0, outputStream.Length, "templateFileName", fileName);

         return x.OpenReadStream();                    
     }
 }
}

